# Recursion in Drracket

Tags: recursion, racket

I am asked to write a racket function repeat-str that consumes a string s with length of n, and produces a new list with length of n. If n is 0, the empty list is produced. If n is greater than 0, the first string in the list contains n copies of n and the second would be n-1 and so fourth.

Ex: `(repeat-str "cat") => (list "catcatcat" "catcat" "cat")`

what I have:

```
(define (repeat-str s)
   (cond
    [(zero? (string-length s)) empty]
    [(equal? (string-length s) 1) s]
    [else (make-list (string-length s) s)
          (repeat-str (make-list (sub1 (string-length s)) s))]))
```

I am trying to recall the the function to get n-1 on the second list but I am unsure how to do the recursion part. This is so I can get 3 separate lists and then append them all at the end.

** cannot use: 
- a placeholder function
- lambda
- replicate function

Using beginning student with list abbreviations

Thank you.

Comment: Make a helper function with `s` in its closure with `n` as the argument so you know how many copies in the string and when to stop. Then just use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
(define (repeat-str str)
  (define (sub cnt rep)
    (if (zero? cnt)
        null
        (cons rep (sub (- cnt 1) (string-append rep str)))))
  (reverse (sub (string-length str) str)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `for/list` with available built-in functions:

```
(define (f s)
  (reverse
   (for/list ((i (string-length s)))
     (apply string-append (make-list (add1 i) s)))))
```

Testing:

```
(f "cat")
```

Output:

```
'("catcatcat" "catcat" "cat")
```